# How to typehint custom classes with mypy

Tags: python, types, mypy

Given the following few modules:

```py
# mod_1.py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class C:
    x : int
```

```py
# mod_2.py
from mod_1 import C

c = C(x = 3)
```

```py
# mod_3.py
from mod_2 import c

def f(something : <type c>) -> None:
    print(c.x)
```

I'm wondering what should be put in place of `<type c>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string if you don't import the type itself.

```
def f(something: 'C') -> None:
    print(c.x)
```

You can also import the type:

```
from mod_2 import c, C

def f(something: C) -> None:
    print(c.x)
```